# Internet explorer 11 jQuery parent.html('') issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

In firefox and chrome the following code works. It populates some html elements using jQuery append command.

```
form_fields.filter('select').each(function() {
    var element=$(this);
    var parent=$(this).parent();

    var label=parent.find('label');

    var select=$('<div class="select-wrapper "></div>').append( parent.find('select') );

    parent.html(''); //removed

    parent.append(label);
    parent.append(select);
});
```

when I test it on Internet explorer the parent element does not get populated. Removing parent.html('') works on internet explorer and the parent label gets populated. Why would this happen?

Comment: Not sure what is "correct", but why are you "killing" the element (`parent.html('');`) if you care about it?

Comment: `.innerHTML.toString()`? `.innerHTML` ___is___ a string.

Comment: setup a MCVE, and explain what you're trying to acheive.

Comment: Also, why not just use jQuerys native solution for this? `label.html()` or `label.first().html()` - jQuery works around quirks.

Comment: @Amit  yes //parent.html(''); removed it and it worked.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes innerHTML is a string but I was afraid that internet explorer did not understand it so I tried that out. Why I am not using native solutions etc.. I am just debugging some piece of code that I never wrote.

Comment: @Amit post your solution. Still I don't understand Why Firefox and Chrome did not have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason for your problem is that by doing:

```
parent.html('');
```

you're emptying the `parent` element, which is an ancestor of `label[0]`. Apparently, that voids `label[0]` (which is surprising to be honest), and as a result `label[0].innerHTML` doesn't work (and probably throws).

You should ***not*** empty the HTML if you want to use the elements inside it.